# How to print different data using div tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div tag

```
<div id="generic" style="color:red;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold"></div>
```

To print the text at that position I am using

```
  document.getElementById("generic").innerHTML= "Please wait";
```

At the same position I need to print a different message in the same file

```
 document.getElementById("generic").innerHTML= "Processing done";
```

Since there are two different messages being printed using the same div tag at different instants in the same file,the first text(please wait) is not being displayed and just the second message(processing done) is getting displayed.

Can someone suggest how this can be rectified to get the first text to be displayed first and later the second text must replace the first text and be displayed in the same place...

Comment: What is your **later** mean?

Comment: May be because your computer is too fast.

Comment: You should use jQuery, can it help you to improve this task.

Comment: When the second innerhtml statement is executed it must replace the first text and should get printed..But the other issue here is that even the first statement is not getting printed..

Comment: @shreya can you please share your js code. Want to know when and how you are calling the second time. Or please share a jsfiddle link

Comment: @shreya — If whatever you want the user to wait for happens so fast that the "please wait" message disappears before anyone can notice it, why do you consider it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

With **setTimeout()** you can display the second message later :

```
function setMessage(id, message) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.innerHTML = message;
}

(function() {
    setMessage("generic", "Please wait");
    var timeGap = 3000; // 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        setMessage("generic", "Processing done"); // Display the second message after 3 seconds
    }, timeGap);
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function updatedText(time){
    var generic = document.getElementById("generic");
        generic.innerHTML= "Please wait";
        setTimeout(function(){
            generic.innerHTML= "After 5 second this text is replace by your previous text";
        }, time);
}
updatedText(5000);
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does. Code-only answers are not helpful.